# How to enable adblock with seleniumlibrary in robotframework

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver, firefox-addon, robotframework

I would like to enable uBlock Origin plugin as ads on speedtest.net during robot framework test execution as ads completly jeopardize test result.

So far I have created a Python script to create a profile with extension

```
from selenium import webdriver

class WebDriverProfile:
    def create_profile_with_adblock(self, path):
        fp =webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        fp.add_extension(extension='d:/pathtoextension/ublock_origin-1.24.0-an+fx.xpi')
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir",path)
        fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 'application/csv')
        fp.update_preferences()
        return fp.path
```

Also the following robot script to call the function:

```
*** settings ***
Library         Selenium2Library
library         Process
library         Dialogs
Library         WebDriverProfile.py

*** Variables ***
${URL}           https://speedtest.net

*** Test Cases ***
Test with speedtest.net
    ${FF_PROFILE}=          Create Profile With Adblock         ${TEMPDIR}\\testdirff
    Open Browser            ${URL}                              browser=ff    ff_profile_dir=${FF_PROFILE}
    Execute Manual Step     Is adblocker enabled?
```

The browser will open, but adblocker won't be there.

Anyone could help on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create webdriver instead of firefox profile and install add-on.

Python extension:

```
from selenium import webdriver

class WebDriverProfile:
    def create_web_driver_with_addons(self):
        extension_location='d:\\path_to_adblock\\ublock_origin-1.24.0-an+fx.xpi'
        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        browser.install_addon(extension_location, temporary=True)
        browser.get('http://speedtest.net')
```

Robot script:

```
*** settings ***
Library         Selenium2Library
library         Process
library         Dialogs
Library         WebDriverProfile.py

*** Variables ***
${URL}           https://speedtest.net

*** Test Cases ***
Test with speedtest.net
    create web driver with addons
    Execute Manual Step     Is adblocker enabled?
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new browser profile with adblock manually installed firest.

Now, Call the above respective profile the by anyone of the below commands.

```
Open Browser    http://example.com  Firefox ff_profile_dir=/path/to/profile # Using profile from disk
Open Browser    http://example.com  Firefox ff_profile_dir=${FirefoxProfile_instance}   # Using instance of FirefoxProfile
Open Browser    http://example.com  Firefox ff_profile_dir=set_preference("key", "value");set_preference("other", "setting")    # Defining profile using FirefoxProfile mehtods~~~
```

Comment: I have tried the first one, where you specify the path to FF profile. FF started up with uBlock, but only for 1 second, after the plug-in was disabled.

Comment: did you create new FF profile with adblock iinstalled? before running the RF line?

Comment: Yes, it was created before